# Electron on click of a button can it execute node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So I have a start button, and once the button is clicked I want it to execute a function.

I know I can execute the function on start of the electron app but is there anyway to say have a start button, and it execute the code on click of the button?

Also I know you can't use node in the browser, and I know Electron uses chromium, but there is still access to node right ?

This is the error I get :

```
Uncaught Exception:
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

index.js

```
    const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const Bot = require('./bot')
// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {

  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: "./bot.js"
    }
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
```

Here is the bot.js file:

```
    const robot = require('robotjs')
const electron = require('electron')
const ipc = electron.ipcRenderer

const Bot = () => {

    const button = document.getElementById('start');
    button.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Click'))
    // button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    //     // Get mouse position.
    //     var mouse = robot.getMousePos();

    //     // Get pixel color in hex format.
    //     var hex = robot.getPixelColor(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    //     console.log("#" + hex + " at x:" + mouse.x + " y:" + mouse.y);
    // });

}


module.exports = Bot;
```

The index.html file :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hello World!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="App">
   <div class="Header">
    <h1>Checkout-Bot</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="Wrapper">
    <p>Click Start</p>
    <button id="start">Start</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this line and `Bot();` from `index.js` to `index.html`:

```js
const Bot = require('./bot')
```

Change this:

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
});
```

To this:

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
  }
});
```

Comment: Okay so I have done this, and on click of the button I get no console output ?

Comment: Write `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();` after you define `mainWindow`, so that you can see the window console.  It's logging to the window console, not to Node's console.

Comment: I already have that enabled.. Nothing is happening in the web console.

Comment: If you write just `button.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Click!'));` does that work?

Comment: no that doesn't work I am going to update the post with the current code.

Comment: Remove `const Bot = require('./bot')` from `index.js`.  And remove `<script defer src="./bot.js"></script>`.

Comment: Okay I removed them, and still nothing in either console on click of the button.

Comment: Remove the line `preload: "./bot.js"`.  Write `<script src="bot.js"></script>` in `index.html` right before `</body>`.  Finally, replace `module.exports = Bot;` with `Bot();`.  This will work because I ran your code to make sure.  Although, I commented out the `robotjs` and `electron-squirrel-startup` stuff.

Comment: Okay thank you helped me find the error, I need robotjs to work is the reason I am doing this will I need to use webpack if I want to get the robotjs code to run on the button click.

Comment: No.  But why did you ask instead of just running the code to see?

Comment: @GrikovArpa I did run the code... the console log works for the example you gave, but it does not work with robotjs. Which is why I asked would I have to use webpack to get the robotjs code to work.

Comment: If it shows an error message, you may need to recompile `robotjs` for the version of Node that Electron is running, like in this answer: https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/issues/466#issuecomment-475954595

Comment: continued along with that and still didn't work. " Loading non-context-aware native module in renderer  " So still the same error as before whenever running with robotjs.

Comment: That seems to be an issue with native modules specifically and separate from the current question, which is accessing Node from an HTML page in Electron.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will do my own research from this point thank you for helping me along to this point!

Answer (score 0):

Electron has a 'renderer' thread for frontend javascript like button clicks. You can run your Bot code from there if you just include the bot.js file in the bottom of your index.html file:

```
<script src="./bot.js"></script>
```

And to allow the use of node you have to set webPreferences.nodeIntegration to true in your browser window:

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    } 
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is you are preloading that JS file before HTML is rendered therefore there no such button exists to attach an event.

Also, I don't see the Bot method is being called. If you don't call Bot() it's not going to attach anything to your button.
Where do you call it? If you forgot, you should add after the button

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Hello World!</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
     </head>
     <body>
      <div class="App">
       <div class="Header">
        <h1>Checkout-Bot</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="Wrapper">
        <p>Click Start</p>
        <button id="start">Start</button>
       </div>
      </div>
      <script>Bot();</script>
     </body>
    </html>
```